# wcf vs web service communication?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, web-services, service

I want to develop a web service or WCF .net application for winforms application development. Which is best for winforms application web service or WCF and why? my application is client server application and the connection is persistent. I am confused that which one is best in this situation.

Comment: WCF **IS** web service - it's not a *WCF or web service* question - that's the **same thing**....

Comment: by revisiting questions youve asked, and selecting answers to mark the question as answered.

Comment: how can i mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF should be preferred, if not for its capabilities than at least for the fact it is more modern and will be supported longer. It also supports net.tcp connections which may work well for the scenario you mentioned (intranet suplex communication)/

Comment: thanks Yaron, but my server is distant .can my application uses nettcp building?

Comment: probably not since the firewall will block it. but basicHttp is still a good option.

Comment: what are the differences between them( nettcp and httpbasic) in my case?

Comment: nettcp is a little faster (not always), and it allows duplex communication so the service can push data to the client. if you need this the client will need to poll the service

Comment: i need a service that returns ( IList) collection of objects or table

Comment: you can do it. anyway web services will not give any advantage over wcf here